# Time Distance Calculation

Tags: education

Two cars started from the same point and traveled on a straight course in opposite directions for exactly 2 hours, at which time they were 208 miles apart. If one car traveled , on average, 8 miles per hour faster than the other car, what was the average speed of each car for the 2-hour trip?

I have the answer as 48 mph and 56 mph. But,  I am not sure how to calculate the Time / Speed / Distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the speed of one car is $v$ mph and that of the other $v+8$ mph, then after two hours they will have travelled $2v$ miles and $2v+16$ miles respectively. Hence, solve
$$2v+(2v+16)\ =\ 208$$